# Error with heroku postgres: database not being uploaded

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku

I'm trying to connect my database to heroku postgres. I successfully created and deployed my app and set all the configurations postgres need to have.

Then I run `heroku run python` and do:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
>>> exit()
```

It does not throws errors here, but then I check my heroku postgres, and my database hasnt been uploaded. Down here are all my configurations from app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

ENV = 'prod'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
if ENV == 'dev':
    app.debug=True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://username:password@server_name:5432/database_name
else:
    app.debug=False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///contaook.db'

app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Also in this app.py I have all my SQLAlchemy databse code. I dont really know If what I'm doing is wrong or this is a common error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works with SQLite databases since Heroku doesn't really support a filesystem... also, you should not post your credentials. I've edited them out.

Comment: You mention that you want the Postgres database initiated, but you have `if ENV == 'dev':` and just before that: `ENV = 'prod'`...

Comment: @mechanical_meat Thank you for that. The ENV = 'prod' i dont really know how this works, I copied it from a tutorial and ended up leaving it

Comment: You're welcome. I would say change the if statement to: `if ENV == 'prod':` and try again.

Comment: @mechanical_meat It`s not working. Postgres is connected but somehow is not importing my local database

Comment: Oh, it isn't meant to import your local database. You'd have to dump and then load it to the remote database... I don't have experience doing that.

Comment: @mechanical_meat Oh ok, by local database I mean the one I have in my Heroku app. Like the one i'm using with the app I uploaded

Comment: Is that database the one that's on EC2?

Comment: it's this one: sqlite:///contaook.db

Comment: Yes, you'd have to dump that database and then load it into the Postgres one. I'm not even sure that would work, though, since they're *very* different database systems.